# Why does defining multiple variables at once result in empty variables, rather than empty strings?

Tags: excel, vba

So, when I define variables and set the values like this:

```
Dim Str1 as String
Dim Str2 as String
Dim Str3 as String

Str1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
Str2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
Str3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
```

As I would expect, the variables contain empty strings (""), since the cell A1 is blank.

However, If I define them like this:

```
Dim Str1, Str2, Str3 as string

Str1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
Str2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
Str3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
```

The variables are empty, and cause errors.

Why does this happen?

Comment: When you use `Dim Str1, Str2, Str3 as string` you end up with variant, variant, string not string, string, string.

Comment: common mis-assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Dim Str1, Str2, Str3 as string` you end up with *variant, variant, string* not *string, string, string*.

For a one line declaration use,

```
Dim Str1 as string, Str2 as string, Str3 as string
```

The VBE's Locals window can quickly confirm your declarations and their status.

Comment: Ah, I thought the whole point of a one line declaration was that you specify the type of groups of variables at once... I may as well just avoid one line declarations altogether. At least I know now. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I guess it boils down to whether you'd rather type *dim* or commas.

Comment: Yeah, I think that declaring them individually is clearer to see at a glance. I was only one lining it because I thought it was quicker since I had a lot of the same type.